# How to scan HBase with specific part of rowkey?

Tags: java, filter, hbase, row-key

For example, rowkey is designed as aabbbbcccc, the bbbb part is the specific part which is used to index the record.
How can I search HBase table with the bbbb part?

Comment: what do you mean `bbbb` is used to index the record?

Comment: My rowkey is composed as type_a|type_b|type_c. And bbbb is type_b part. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

You can use the RowFilter with the [SubstringComparator](https://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/filter/SubstringComparator.html) on Scan object to fetch matching records.  Note this will require a full scan of all the data.

```
Scan scan = new Scan();

scan.setFilter(new RowFilter(CompareOp.EQUAL, new SubstringComparator("bbbb")));

scan.addFamily(Bytes.toBytes("columnFamily"));
ResultScanner scanner = table.getScanner(scan);
```

Comment: sorry for the confusion describe of my question. And I explain it more explicitly. My rowkey is type_a|type_b|type_c, and I want to get row specified by type_b part. How can I achieve this? Or can I achieve this in HBase? Thanks a lot for your anwser.